# Entity Framework 7 (core) Find entity based on composite key?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there a method or workaround to find entity based on composite key? When using Entity Framework 7 (core).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.State, c.LicensePlate });
```

Specially to avoid UNIQUE constrain exceptions with many-to-many intermediate table.

Comment: Usually I use a Context with DBSets of the entities. Then I can do something like: _context.Cars.Where(c => c.State != null && c.LicensePlate != null).ToList(); if those properties are objects. Or you check against what ever value would be "null".  != 0.   Does this help you a little?

Comment: ah yes, simple approach and it works. Mainly I needed to check if entity with certain composite key already existed in the database. I used this type of call: `database.Cars.Any(
                c => c.StateId == stateId && c.LicensePlateId == LicensePlateId)`

Comment: Do I put it as answer, so this can be closed? Or do you still need some help?

Comment: worked for me, i guess therefore viable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I use a Context with DBSets of the entities. Then I can do something like:

```
 _context.Cars.Where(c => c.State != null && c.LicensePlate != null).ToList();
```

Or you check against whatever value would be "null". != 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use also Find method after 1.1 release:

```
var entity = _context.Cars.Find(firstKey, secondKey);
```